# How to deploy Qt applications on remote Windows 10 tablets?

Tags: qt, deployment, qt-creator

I would like to deploy my Qt app on my remote tablet (Galaxy Book with Windows 10) from my Windows 10 PC. Visual Studio provides this functionality with the [Remote Tools for Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/run-windows-store-apps-on-a-remote-machine?view=vs-2019#BKMK_download) and allows to directly run the app on the tablet using the local network. I would like to do the same thing with Qt Creator. I can see [in the documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.12/winrt-support.html#building-applications-with-qt-creator) that this might not be possible, but that page could be outdated. So is there way to remotely debug and deploy Qt applications on remote PCs without manually creating an installer?

Comment: https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_remotely_debug_Qt_applications

Comment: @VahagnAvagyan The article mentions "This is a guide to write a Qt program on one virtual PC, and deploy and debug it on another virtual PC" so it is not aimed at physical devices.

Comment: I don't see anything there that wouldn't work with physical devices. The problem is that it's for Linux though.

Comment: This guide assumes a windows 7 host system, but this should work on each platform that can run Virtualbox.

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-debugger-operating-modes.html#remote-debugging